Handling non-constructor properties when converting Kotlin data classes from JSON
I'm working on a project where we need to serialize/deserialize Kotlin data classes to/from JSON using the GSON library. The class I am working on looks like:
data class Request(val parent_identifier: String?=null, val identifier: String, val display_name: String,
                       val bssid: String, val company_address: LocationAddress,
                       val minimum_match_criteria: Boolean=false, val public_ip:String, val private_ip:String, val network_switches: List<ZoomNetworkSwitch>): HasUid {
        override val uid: String
            get() = display_name

        val country = company_address.country
        val address_line1 = company_address.address_line1
        val address_line2 = company_address.address_line2
        val city = company_address.city
        val state_code = company_address.state_code
        val zip = company_address.zip
}

Note the accessor properties for getting the data for the nested address. If I call gson().fromJson() with the json string:
    {
            "display_name": "7th St Café",
            "private_ip": "111.0.0.0/16",
            "public_ip": "123.0.0.0/16",
            "identifier": "CAFE",
            "company_address": {
                "address_line1": "420 S 7th St",
                "address_line2": "7th St Café",
                "city": "Lewisburg",
                "country": "US",
                "state_code": " PA",
                "zip": " 17837"
            },
            "network_switches": [
                {
                    "mac_address": "00:bd:9e:ff:27:00"
                }
            ]
    }

and look at the resulting object, the constructor properties will be initialized, but all of the non-constructor properties will be null. What do I need to do to get Gson to properly initialize this class?


Migrate from GSON (recommended)
change your accessors to actually be accessors (get() =  declaration like your uid) and not copy company_address fields.

1 - GSON does not actually support kotlin and it never will as it's "feature complete" and in maintenance. So things like default values in constructors are completely ignored.
What's worse it's reflection based so how it works is forcefully create new instance with null in every field then fill them in (also using reflection). If I recall correctly it even omits constructor/init blocks in this process.
2 - Currently your "accessors" are fields as far as it understands so it tries to carry them over from your json string but it does not contain any of those values so they remain null.

"it even omits constructor/init blocks"; depends on whether the class has a no-args constructor, see also GsonBuilder.disableJdkUnsafe(). (But Gson is nonetheless not that well suited for Kotlin.)
